# Multiple Excel multiplications

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am not sure how to explain this but here we go:

I need to multiply a range of costs with various volumes. I need to multiply each cost (Cost 1, Cost 2), with the volume, and get the overall total with each cost multiplied. With limitations on the excel file I am using, I can not just do a multiply under each cost and then work out the total, and I do not want to put 1 massive formula in to manually multiply each and then ad together.

I am not sure if there is a function which I have missed - assume if there is it will be really obvious.

[image: Table Screenshot]

Comment: Both rows at once: `=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$N$2,($B3:$N3+$B4:$N4))`. Even better `=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$N$2*$B3:$N4)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$N$2,$B3:$N3)
```